# How do I effectively set the DataContext of a StaticResourceExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I am trying to reduce code duplication.  Consider the following:

```
<page...>
  <page.resources>
    <MenuItem x:Key="commonItem" />
  </page.resources>
  <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.Resources>
          <local:thingOne x:Key="one"/>
          <local:thingTwo x:Key="two"/>
        </ContextMenu.Resources>
        <StaticResourceExtension PropertyKey="commonItem"/>
        <StaticResourceExtension PropertyKey="commonItem"/>
      </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
  </TextBlock>
</page>
```

How do I pass "one" to the first commonItem instance and "two" to the second?

I realize given the above example there would be a better way to do this, this is an extremely trimmed down version of what is really going on in our XAML.

More generally the question is, how do I follow good DRY principles when I have context menus all over the app that are different, but share some similar menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, I realized I was trying to be too complicated.  Here is what I did:

Add a custom menu item type:

```
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem {}
```

And in the proper scope context (for me it was global):

```
<Style TargetType="namespace:MyMenuItem">
    <!-- common control internals -->
</Style>
```

When it is needed to be used:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
      <local:thingOne x:Key="one"/>
      <local:thingTwo x:Key="two"/>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
    <namespace:MyMenuItem DataContext={Binding one}/>
    <namespace:MyMenuItem DataContext={Binding two}/>
</ContextMenu>
```

This approach allows setting the DataContext and allows for automatic style application when combined with other MenuItems in a MenuBase control that need to have a different behavior.

One would expect a named style could be applied and a simple menu item could be used.  I tried that and it did not work.  I expect somewhere along the way something was overriding this for a MenuItem, but does not for a MenuItem derived type.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't put a `MenuItem` in your `Resources`. This will just create a single instance of a MenuItem, and because it's a `UIElement` it can only be used in one location on your Page.

You could instead keep a `Style` for a MenuItem in your resources, with all setting that are common to most MenuItems, and apply that style to your items. Tip: If you omit the `x:Key` from your `Style` and just give it a `TargetType`, it will be applied to *all* `MenuItems`:

```
<Page...>
    <Page.resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" >
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Lime" />
        </Style>
    </Page.resources>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <local:thingOne x:Key="one"/>
                    <local:thingTwo x:Key="two"/>
                </ContextMenu.Resources>
                <MenuItem DataContext="{StaticResource one}" />
                <MenuItem DataContext="{StaticResource two}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</Page>
```

Comment: You can fix the first problem you referenced by adding x:Shared="False" in the menu item declaration in the resources.  I can not use a style "easily".  I am currently making this a custom control, but it is not going well.